# Ant regex to find two kind of files

Tags: regex, ant

I am using regex in a ant file to identify two kind of files:

. Files that finish with *.bin.zip
. Files that finish with *[0-9].zip

I am using the or (|) condition to merge it but it is not working:

```
<fileset dir="${project.folder}/target/build">
   <filename regex=".*[0-9].zip | .*bin.zip"/>
</fileset>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: How about `.*[0-9]\.zip$|.*bin\.zip$` ?

Comment: `$` means end of matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your regex; they are being counted in the pattern.

```
<fileset dir="${project.folder}/target/build">
   <filename regex=".*[0-9].zip|.*bin.zip"/>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try without the spaces:

```
<filename regex=".*[0-9].zip|.*.bin.zip"/>
```

Or better:

```
<filename regex=".*([0-9]|.bin).zip"/>
```